# How do I read my saved .wav file as byte or double array? I am using Java / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to read a .wav file, convert it into double array and FFT the array.

I have the recorded .wav file in storage but I have no idea how I can read the file and use the data.

I am a beginner in application development so it would be nice if you could lead me through step by step as well as show some sample code.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I would say this would be a perfect case for a search engine. There are surely many examples about reading files and it doesn’t really suit this site’s function, which is to help with specific programming problems, not to work as a tutorial site on basic functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've been searching for hours but there seems to be not much answer out there. It's not that I'm asking for tutorials but I would love to know how to tackle this issue. So to answer your comment, should I give a more specific example like show my code?? Was my question not specific enough?? I just started using this site. I'm sorry if I did something that I wasn't supposed to do.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you searched for “read file in java” and “read file in android” and it provided no results? My search shows a lot of examples of that. If that is not the actual problem then please do edit the question and be more specific about the problem.

Comment: I am trying to construct a byte array or double array by reading a .wav file in android studio. I guess I could be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you a full code since it's a long solution and I have other things to do. I can give you hints.

First, check this [link](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) as reference.

As you see, a .wav or a WAVE file does not only contain the audio samples but it also contains other metadata that describes the contents of the file. To correctly read the audio samples, you'll need the values of these metadata.

To do this, first instantiate a `FileInputstream`. You will need a `File` object representing your .wav file to do that.

Next, you'll need to read each field from top to bottom. As you see from the illustration, the number of bytes for each field is indicated. Use the following code when reading a field.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
fileInputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
// The value of current field is now stored in the bytes array
```

After each read, the `fileInputStream` will automatically point to the next field. Just repeat the above code until you have reached the start of the audio samples data.

To interpret the obtained values, you'll have to carefully read the description of each field.

To convert field from byte array to ASCII or String, use:

```
String value = new String(bytes);
```

To convert field from byte array to a number, use:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(numOfBytes);
buffer.order(BIG_ENDIAN); // Check the illustration. If it says little endian, use
// LITTLE_ENDIAN
buffer.put(bytes);
buffer.rewind();
```

If field consists of two bytes:

```
Short value = buffer.getShort();
```

If field consists of 4 bytes:

```
Int value = buffer.getInt();
```

To read the samples, just continue what you're doing above. But you'll also have to consider the number of bits per sample as given by the `BitsPerSample` field. For 8 bits, read 1 byte. For 16 bits, read 2 bytes, and so on and so forth. Just repeat to get each sample until you reach the end of file.
To check the end of file, get the returned value from read and check if it is -1:

```
int read = fileInputSream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
// If read equals -1 then end of file
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful and you make it easy to understand.